# "No such file or directory" error message when using psql's \copy command

Tags: postgresql

I keep having a error message of "No such file or directory" for this psql's \copy command:

`\copy household from '/home/kihong/hh.csv' with csv header;`

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: "*Do you have any suggestions*": apparently the file or directory does not exist on the computer where you run `psql`

Comment: Maybe the file is server-side? If so you have to use `COPY` not `\copy`. Otherwise: File doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would move the file to different folder (This worked for me). I tried to upload my CSV file from desktop and got the error message you got.  Also as Craig Ringer suggested use copy instead of \copy.

Here is the step by step instruction on how to load data from spreadsheet (Excel or OpenOffice Calc) into postgreSQL:

Save the spreadsheet page as a CSV file. Prefered method is to open the spreadsheet on OpenOffice Calc and do the saving. On “Export to text file” window choose Character Set as Unicode (UTF8), Field Delimiter: “,” and Text Delimiter “ “ “. Message will be displayed saying only active sheet is saved. Note: This file has to be saved on a folder but not on desktop and have to save in UTF8 format (postgreSQL by dafault is step up for UTF8 encoding). If saved on desktop, postgreSQL will give “access denied” message and won't upload.

In PostgreSQL, create an empty table with same number of column as the spreadsheet.

Note: On each column, column-name has to be same, data type has to be same. Also, keep in mind the length of data where character varying with enough field.

Then on postgreSQL, on SQL window, put the code:

copy "ABC"."def" from E'C:\\tmp\\blabla.csv' delimiters ',' CSV HEADER;

NOTE: Here C:\\tmp is the folder where CSV-file “blabla” is saved. “ABC”.”def” is the table created on postgreSQL where "ABC" is the schema and "def" is the table. Then do “execute query” by pressing the green button on top. “CSV HEADER” is needed when CSV table has heading at the start of every column.

If everythig is ok, no error message will be displayed and table data from CSV file will be loaded into the postgreSQL table. But if there is an error message do as following:

If error message is saying that the data is too long for a specific column, then increase the column size. This happens mostly on character and character varying column. Then run the “execute query” command again.

If error message is saying that the data type doesn't match to a particular column, then change the data type on postgreSQL table-column to match the one in CSV table.